# Not recording all controls properly

Tags: c#, winappdriver

I am working to record the user activity using WinAppDriver recorder application. There is a specific use case where I need the help...

- The tab key doesn't work. So basically if I am on user control and I press the tab, then it doesn't give the XPath of current control where tab arrived.

Example below:[If after adding symbol I press tab key, the control is now on Account but recorder still showing XPath for Symbol text box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLluO.png)

- If there is a combo box in the user interface and If I double click on the next control after selecting the combo value, then it picks up the XPath of combo and not of  the next control.

Example below:[If after selecting Unallocated from Account combo box I double click Quantity text box, then it still showing XPath for Account combo box and not for quantity text box until I hover the mouse a few times.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ssqy.png)

Comment: Paste the images here instead of providing a link to them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I am using open source WinApp driver microsoft application to logs the activity of my application and as per functionality of WinApp driver it fetches the Xpath of elements , when any action is performed like mouse click , mouse hover , mouse move , key  press but it is missing some events  as described above with TAB key.